Left-menu should scroll with page, but only until it reaches the bottom
I have a classic website with a menu on the left side and content on the right. The menu is fairly long, but on some pages, the content is really long. So I wanted the menu to always be accessible to the left, even though you had scrolled way down. I've accomplished this in the following manner:
<body>
  <div id="header" style="z-index:-1;">
    <div id="menu" style="position:fixed;top:0px;height:2000px;overflow:hidden;">
      Menu contents
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main" style="margin-left:180px;margin-top:0px;z-index:100;">
    Main page contents
  </div>
</body>

and with additional styles
div#menu
{
  float: left;
}
div#main
{
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
}

My problem is that for small viewports, the bottom of the menu is below the viewport, and it doesn't scroll. I would like to have the menu scroll with the contents of the page, but only until it reaches the bottom of the menu. After that, the content should go on scrolling without the menu.
Would that be possible?
I haven't tried anything yet, because I'm unsure what to try.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Frankly though, since the page is currently using float and position:fixed it could probably use a complete rewrite to bring it out of the 1990's. There are significantly better and more modern layout methods now.

Thanks, @Paulie_D, would you happen to know where I can read more about more modern layout methods? I suspected this was "old school" :-)

. Check out LearnLayout.com

'float' is not for layout styling
how about this?
The scrollbar needs to be customized.


body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div#menu
{
  background: #222;
  position:fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
div#menu .inner {
  height: 2000px;
}
div#main
{
  padding: 20px;
  height: 2000px;
}
<body>
  <div id="header" style="z-index:-1;">
    <div id="menu">
      <div class="title">Menu header</div>
      <div class="inner">
        Menu contents
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main" style="margin-left:180px;margin-top:0px;z-index:100;">
    Main page contents
  </div>
</body>



